# React useEffect is called only once on batched requests

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an application where I have a form. In this form, I need to wait for the user to not have inputted anything for 200ms before validating. I am doing that with a promise, but now there are other ways for the "wait 200ms and then validate" promise to be triggered (for example, setting your focus on the field also triggers validation after 200ms - the idea is that if you don't start typing in the first 200ms, the field will show you the errors for the empty input).

The problem with that is that, when React batches requests, useEffect is called only on the last value and I use useEffect to cleanup the promises (which are wrapped timeouts with cancellation provided by Bluebird).

Here is example code which shows my problem, but instead does it with buttons: https://codesandbox.io/s/lively-flower-3w3lc?file=/src/App.js.

Here, if I have one button, it works as expected - it only logs "Hey" once I've stopped clicking. However, it doesn't work with two buttons. How can I make it work? Is there a way to stop just these requests from batching, if that's needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use ref as shown below. Invoking `seState` to cache reference to the timeout will trigger re-render, which I believe is not intended here.

```
function App() {
  const timeouts = useRef(new Map());

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      Array.from(timeouts.current.values()).forEach(clearTimeout);
    };
  }, []);

  function setNewTimeout(name) {
    if (timeouts.current.has(name)) {
      clearTimeout(timeouts.current.get(name));
    }
    timeouts.current.set(name, (setTimeout(() => console.log("Hey", name), 2000)));
  }

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => {setNewTimeout("button1")}}>test</button>
      <button onClick={() => {setNewTimeout("button2")}}>CLICK ME</button>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

[image: Edit wonderful-ives-4go6f]

Comment: Thank you! useRef is exactly what I needed.